# How can I check if a number is negative?

Tags: python

I tried to check if the number is negative or not:

```
x = int(input('Enter any number:'))
bumble = x+1
shumble = x-1
if shumble>x:
  print('Your number is a negative number')

elif bumble>x:
  print('Your number is a positive number')

elif x == 0:
  print('Your number is 0')
```

but the problem is python won't consider a negative number its **mathematical value**
and I checked that by running this block of code

```
x = -2
y = 1 
if x>y:
  print('-2 is greater that 1')

elif y>x::
  print('1 is greater than -2')
```

and the output says:

> -2 is greater than 1
> so can someone pls help me find a solution?
> I would really appreciate it!

Comment: `x-1` is **not** greater than `x` for negative numbers. You need to get your understanding of arithmetic straightened out.

Comment: Your second block doesn't do what you say either - it raises a SyntaxError, and if you remove the extra colon, it prints `1 is greater than -2`.

Comment: oh :( can you tell me a way to check if a number is a negative number?

Comment: Hint: what's the relationship between a negative number and 0?

Comment: hm? oh! thanks man!

Comment: why not just do `if x < 0:`?

Comment: @MaheepSingh i think you get the downvotes because you do not understand basic arithmetic ... a negative number is smaller than 0 ...

Comment: yeah i didn't think of that

Comment: i accidently put the wrong symbl

Comment: my fault didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether or not you're not allowed to use zero with you inequality operator. But surely the following should work pretty well. You can omit the exception handling if not needed.

```
try:
    x = int(input('Enter any number:'))
    if x < 0:    print('Your number is a negative number')
    elif x > 0:    print('Your number is a positive number')
    elif x == 0:    print('Your number is 0')
except ValueError:
    print("That was not a valid number...")
```

Answer (score -1):

You're overcomplicating this so much. To check if its a negative number check if its less than, equal to, or greater than zero

```py
try:
  x = int(input("Enter a number"))
except:
  print("invalid number")

if x > 0:
  print("Positive")
elif x < 0:
  print("Negative")
else:
  print("Equal to 0")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
num = float(input("Enter a number: "))

if num > 0:
    print("{0} is a positive number".format(num))
elif num == 0:
    print("{0} is zero".format(num))
else:
    print("{0} is negative number".format(num))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28066423)

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj This does actually ***attempt*** to answer the question. Please don't recommend deletion posts that are not accurate or might be altogether wrong. The review queue is for removing posts that are not at all attempting to answer, like thank-you notes or "I'm having the same problem"

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.